# setting up a tunnel for rsync with jsch

Tags: java, rsync, jsch

I need to sync files using rsync. I'm currently writing a java application that will act as a front end for the rsync application. I need to be able to set up a secure connection via ssh so the rsync can be used over the network. We'd like to keep dependencies to a minimum so we'd like to use jsch for setting up the connection. We have an ssh server running which also has a rsync daemon running on port 1800. Connecting to the ssh server is no problem.

Now to connect to the rsync daemon i thought it would be enough to set up local port forwarding like this:

```
int TunnelLocalPort = 873;
int TunnelRemotePort = 1800;
session.setPortForwardingL(TunnelLocalPort, "localhost", TunnelRemotePort);
```

this however does not work. Is this the correct way to accomplish this? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does the same thing work if you try rsync and ssh from the command line?